# Calculate the duration difference between 2 formatted time fields in Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to get duration between 2 formatted time columns (Start Time & End Time). Newbie with the Google App Scripts. Please guide me how to achieve that.

```
var a = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,7).getValue()
var b = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,8).getValue()
var c = (b-a).getTime();
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,9).setValue(c);
```

[image: Here is an image attached for the google sheet]

Comment: Just to be clear, this is something you need done as part of a script?  You don't want just a formula to do this in a sheet instead?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know is how Sheets and Apps Script interpret date formats. Google uses [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) on it's products, so it starts at `00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970`. Not specifying the date means Sheets interprets `09:00:00` as `Sat Dec 30 17:09:21 GMT+00:09 1899`.

In your case it wouldn't make a major difference since you are deducing dates, but I recommend you write them like `30/05/2020 09:00:00`, and then go to `Format > Number > Time`.

Regarding Apps Script, [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) will interpret it as something similar to `Mon Dec 30 18:00:00 GMT+02:00 2020`, which is not useful. Use the [Date](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_date_object.htm) Javascript method to format it to a Date object. Then you can use getTime to get it in milliseconds (everything here works in milliseconds):

Once you have both time values in milliseconds, you can operate with them. You have to convert them to hours (1 milliseconds = 3.6e+6 hours):

```
var a = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,7).getValue()
var b = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,8).getValue()

var a1 = new Date(a).getTime(); //Time in milliseconds
var b1 = new Date(b).getTime(); //Time in milliseconds

var hours = (b1 - a1) / 3.6e+6;

e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,9).setValue(hours);
```

> This won't work well for minutes. 1h and 30 minutes will be 1,5 hours.

---

**Function's solution:**

Instead of Apps Script, use Sheets formulas to calculate it. It's as simple as setting, for example C1, to `=B1-A1`;

[image]